# How do you use an array list in multiple classes?

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, arraylist

I want to store the input in my dictionary class so that I can search the words within this class. But I also need to use the array in other classes. Does anyone have an idea of how I can add input to my Dictionary() constructor?

Does anyone have an idea of how to fix this??

Thank you so much in advance!!!!

```
public class Dictionary {
  // Private data fields
  public ArrayList<String> dict;

  Dictionary() {
    dict = new ArrayList<String>();

  }

  public void add (String s){
    dict.add(s);
  }

  public int size (){
    return dict.size();
  }

  public String get(int i) {
    return dict.get(i);
  }

  public ArrayList<String> getList(){
    return dict;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    if (args.length < 1) {
      System.out.print("Must have a file.");
      System.exit(1);
    }

    try {
      File dictionaryFile = new File(args[0]);

      Scanner fin = new Scanner(dictionaryFile);

      System.out.println(dictionaryFile.getAbsolutePath());

      if (!dictionaryFile.exists()) {
        System.out.println("Dictionary " + args[0] + "does not exist");
      }

      else if (!dictionaryFile.canRead()) {
        System.out
            .println("Dictionary " + args[0] + " cannot be read.");
      }
      Dictionary dict = new Dictionary();
      while (fin.hasNext()) {
        dict.add(fin.nextLine());
      }

      for (int i = 0; i < dict.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(dict.get(i));
      }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      System.out.println("No such file found " + args[0]);
    }
 }
}

/**
 *This is the class I want to reference the array in 
 */
public class FindWords {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Dictionary dictionary = new Dictionary();
    System.out.print(dictionary.getList());

  }
}
```

Comment: In which class you are facing trouble accessing the arraylist?

Comment: I want to be able to use the dict ArrayList in another class called FindWords. However, I am either unable to reference the dict or it prints as an empty list.

Comment: Probably there is some problem in your FindWords class. better show that code

Comment: This is the code for FindWords, it returns an empty list no matter what the list is in my original class. public class: FindWords {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  Dictionary dictionary = new Dictionary();
  System.out.print(dictionary.getList());
  
 }

Comment: you are creating a whole new instance of Dictionary class. So there's no chance of getting the string you have inserted in the dictionary earlier.

Comment: Your code looks fine - you haven't added any entries to your dictionary so it's going to be empty, so when you print it in `main`, it'll simply be an empty list. Add some `dictionary.add("...")` first and see the result.

Comment: I was wondering if you have suggestions for how to add user content from the console to the class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay...the problem is you are creating a new dictionary object in this class and your array list is associated with an Object or it is defined at the object level.

So, a new arraylist gets created everytime you instantiate a Dictionary object.

Try, making the arraylist as static in your Dictionary class.

for example,

```
public static ArrayList<String> yourArrayList;
```

Now, once you have added some elements in your Dictionary in the main method, you can access that array list from FindWord class like

```
Dictionary.dict
```

or, if you are not in a position to take that decision of making array list static in dictionary class then you need to initialize the list in FindWord class too as your FindWord class code shows that you are not adding elements in the dict list here.

Here, let me try again.

Why **null**?

```
public class: FindWords { 
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        Dictionary dictionary = new Dictionary();//1

        /***
        . your list initialization code should come here
        . It could be a code block or a method defined in Dictionary class itself
        . which can be called like dictionary.initializeList();
        ***/
        System.out.print(dictionary.getList()); //3

    }
}
```

here, dictionary object has an arraylist associated with it(true) but it is not initialized yet. So, when you are saying

```
        dictionary.getList();
```

it is actually fetching you the uninitialized list.

Comment: downvoting without comments is rude.

Comment: Hey Tirath! Thank you so much - unfortunately the output is null when I do this. Where exactly should I put public static ArrayList<String> yourArrayList;
??? Perhaps, I placed it in the wrong line?

Comment: @Theodore You have the main method defined in both Dictionary and FindWords class(code that you have shared). Can you tell me like when do you want the array list defined in the Dictionary class to be filled with dictionary items?

Comment: I want my array list to be populated with dictionary items in the Dictionary Class, under main, when it is reading lines from the file. And just for Find Words (and other classes) to be able to reference this. Thank you so much. I appreciate this a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your findwords class a s following

```
       public class FindWords {

       Dictionary dict=null;

       public void (Dictionary dict){
                  this.dict = dict;
       }


       public void print(){
       for(int i=0;i<dict.getList.size();i++)
       {
                      System.out.println(dict.getList.get(i));
       }
```

}

after that just before fininshing your try block add the following lines

```
     FindWords f = new FindWords(dict);
    f.print();
```